# Shiny-Server with Apache WebSocket fail

Tags: r, websocket, shiny, shiny-server

I'm new to servers. I installed an Apache web server on Ubuntu 20.04, with and secured the connection with Let's Encrypt. Then I set up a Shiny server (latest Version) and set up the following forwarding in Apache (according to the template).

```
 <Proxy *>
    Allow from localhost
  </Proxy>
 
RedirectMatch permanent ^/app$ /app/
 
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket
RewriteRule /app/(.*) ws://localhost:3838/$1 [P,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} !=websocket
RewriteRule /app/(.*) http://localhost:3838/$1 [P,L]
ProxyPass /app/ http://localhost:3838/
ProxyPassReverse /app/ http://localhost:3838/
 
Header edit Location ^/ /app/
ProxyRequests Off
```

I can call up my Shiny-app on my mobile phone as well as on the desktop at home (everything works). In our company network, it loads the website first, but not the interactive parts - and then the entire page turns gray.

Based on research, it appears to be a problem with the websockets and the firewall oft the company. The same app on shinyapps.io works. I can find the following error message in the web browser:

```
sockjs-0.3.4.min.js:27 WebSocket connection to 'wss://srv.socialthink.net/app/uster-kultur/__sockjs__/n=kNUaoWz4VkbEoGT2f8/464/b_7zv2u0/websocket' failed:
```

I found a similar description of the problem, but no workaround to fix the problem.

I don't know how to continue looking, are there any ideas?